# Google Sheets Query - Omit Empty Cells and Sort Simultaneously

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have been merging data from several google sheets using the QUERY function. My goal is also to omit empty cells and sort after a specific column (second column). However, depending on what I try, I receive an Error! or Value! error.

I have been using the following function:

`= QUERY({'Raw Data A'!A5:A,'Raw Data A'!C5:C;'Raw Data B'!A5:A,'Raw Data B'!C5:C})`

with this function I was able to successfully merge all the data (from sheet A and B, two colums each).

Now, for omitting empty cells I used the following updated variant:

`= QUERY({'Raw Data A'!A5:A,'Raw Data A'!C5:C;'Raw Data B'!A5:A,'Raw Data B'!C5:C}, "select * where Col1<>''")`

This also works perfecty, however, I would like to sort after values (Date) in the second column as well. For this I tried:

`= QUERY({'Raw Data A'!A5:A,'Raw Data A'!C5:C;'Raw Data B'!A5:A,'Raw Data B'!C5:C}, "ORDER BY 2")`

This also worked as intended (however, empty cells were also included).

So I tried to combine these two functions, but nothing works.

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=QUERY({'Raw Data A'!A5:A,'Raw Data A'!C5:C;'Raw Data B'!A5:A,'Raw Data B'!C5:C},"Where Col1 is not null order by Col2 DESC")
```

- you can just remove the `DESC` part if the sort is supposed to be ascending.

Comment: This did work very well, thank you so much. However, now the following issue appeared. Because the dates in column 2 are in the format "dd.mm.yyyy" the function first sorts after the days, then after the months, etc, and is not actually sorting after the date. How could I solve this?

Comment: you can try something alike the one shown in the screenshot(https://i.imgur.com/5SA9Eve.png) to convert the text-date to valid date format `=int(substitute(J5,".","/"))`. Please do share a sample sheet with demo data if its somehow not working on your end.